# ERROR: too many dynamic shared memory segments

Tags: postgresql

**Error:**

```
2020-04-25 05:42:49.617 EDT [11233] ERROR:  could not map dynamic shared memory segment
2020-04-25 05:42:49.617 EDT [11234] ERROR:  could not map dynamic shared memory segment
2020-04-25 05:42:49.628 EDT [3938] someuser@somedb ERROR:  too many dynamic shared memory segments
```

This dynamic shared memory error has started to show in the log.

Should I need to reduce work_mem?

**PostgreSQL version:** `postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)`

Comment: Is this the only ERROR, or is there an immediately preceding one?  Can you show the query?  I would not expect work_mem to be relevant here.

Comment: Yes, there was a nested query statement followed by parallel failed warning:

2020-04-25 05:42:49.870 EDT [11238] ERROR:  could not map dynamic shared memory segment
2020-04-25 05:42:49.872 EDT [25932] LOG:  worker process: parallel worker for PID 3939 (PID 11237) exited with exi
t code 1

Answer (score 0):

```
shmmax_limit=$(sysctl -n kernel.shmmax)
echo "System limits:"
echo "shmall: $shmall_limit"
echo "shmmax: $shmmax_limit"

postgresql_conf="/path/to/postgresql.conf"  # Replace with the actual path to postgresql.conf
shared_buffers_new="16MB"  # Adjust the new value as needed
sed -i "s/^shared_buffers *=.*/shared_buffers = $shared_buffers_new/" $postgresql_conf

sudo systemctl restart postgresql

echo "PostgreSQL restarted successfully."
```

Checking system limits, adjusting PostgreSQL configuration, and restarting PostgreSQL

Comment: The summary is good. The answer could be improved by explaining each option, to help future visitors. Links to references would be even better.